# Recording from Soundcard Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, pulseaudio, soundcard, audio-recording

I switched from the gnome panel desktop environment to xfce recently, and I just noticed that I can no longer record sound using the pulseaudio command line. The command I am using is `parec -d combined.monitor | oggenc -b 320 --managed -o test.ogg --raw -`. I mirrored the sound from the application to all output sinks using pulseaudio, which generates the combined.monitor source. On a possibly related note, I cannot extract audio from youtube videos using `youtube-dl`.

Comment: Further testing seems to indicate the problem is with PulseAudio. I tried similar encoding outputs with lame and it recorded the same silence, though VLC could detect a length. The act of recording is being detected by pulse from the correct source. When I trace the sound through PulseAudio devices, the volume meter doesn't even show something for the combined monitor, even though it says the application is routing sound through it.

Comment: I finally fixed this issue today. If you delete ~/.pulse and restart, it should fix itself. Apparently some file in ~/.pulse had some errors or something. I really don't understand it; another forum suggested creating a new user, which worked. Deleting the directory and restarting seemed a similar approach. If you have some insight as to why this worked, I would love to know.

Answer (score 2):

The OP solved this problem (and reported it in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107214/recording-from-soundcard-ubuntu-11-04#comment140961_107214)). Excerpted:

> I finally fixed this issue today. If you delete ~/.pulse and restart,
>   it should fix itself. Apparently some file in ~/.pulse had some errors
>   or something. I really don't understand it; another forum suggested
>   creating a new user, which worked. Deleting the directory and
>   restarting seemed a similar approach.